# Where is the jumper Point to short to bios CMOS on my Toshiba satellite U-505 s2005 laptop

Tags: bios, cmos, jumper

Where can I find the CMOS jumper points on my Toshiba satellite U-505 s2005 laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Many laptop motherboards do not actually have such jumpers. You can simply take out the CMOS battery, wait a few (10) seconds, and plug it in again. You will achieve the same result.

You can check [this picture](http://www.irisvista.com/tech/laptops/Toshiba-Satellite-U505-U500-U505D/Toshiba-Satellite-U500-U505/laptop-base-big/Satellite-U505-disassembly-22.jpg) to see where the CMOS battery is.